# Elixir `ListDict` is deprecated, so what should I to `get` a value from a list, while the key is a binary

Tags: elixir

I just updated `Elixir` version to `v0.13.2`, and found `ListDict` is deprecated, and what should I handle these `Dict` apis, like I want to get the value of `[{"foo", :bar}]` key `"foo"`.  In `Elixir` v0.13 or before, I can just use `Dict.get([{"foo", :bar}], "foo")` to get the value, now I can't do it, otherwise it throws `no function clause matching in Keyword.get/3`, or should I just use the `List.keyfind/3`(which can get the correct key-value pair), but I think which is not a convenience way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert those lists to a HashDict quite easily, and then manipulate them as usual via the `Dict` API by using `Enum.into/2`:

```
listdict = [{"foo", :bar}, {"baz", :qux}]
listdict |> Enum.into(HashDict.new) |> Dict.get("foo")
```

You can also do this via comprehensions like so:

```
for {k, v} <- listdict, into: HashDict.new, do: {k, v}
```

Or even:

```
for keypair <- listdict, into: HashDict.new, do: keypair
```